# Safe exiting an Application from a ExceptionHandler subclass?

Tags: java, android, exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler, system.exit

I'm new to Android as well as java, i'll try my best to be as specific as possibe.

I have an app with one activity and several fragments and classes along with an `ExceptionHandler` subclass which implements default `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. I was able to successfully use :-

`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));`

to exit an application in case of unhandled exceptions without displaying the `"ForceClose"` pop-up. I use `System.exit(0)` . I'm recording logs throughtout the application. I'm able to record the exception from  ExceptionHandler subclass into the log.

Now, my issue is that the application exits without undergoing `onPause()`,`onStop()` or `onDestroy()` in case of an uncaught exception, but i need it to pass through all these lifecycles for my `MainActivity`.

How can i do this while exiting the application using the `ExceptionHandler` subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally got it, if the error is thrown in the first activity(MainActivity) which is launched then nothing can be done.

If it is thrown in anyother activity, then in the `ExceptionHandler` class we can pass the intent to start the MainActivity and then exit the app. gracefully :P

`public class ExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler{`

```
private Activity myContext;
public ExceptionHandler(Activity context) {
    this.myContext = context;
}
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
    String report = stackTrace.toString();

    if(myContext instanceof MainActivity){

        System.gc();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

    }else{

        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        myContext.startActivity(intent);
        System.gc();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

    }
}
```

`}`